# Mostrar columnas que tengan valor SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas tengo esta tabla que tiene como 100 columnas como la imagen y el query pero lo que yo quiero es solo obtener las columnas que tengan monto

solo optener estas columnas :

- Numeroprestamo
- NumeroCuota
- Fechavencimiento
- las columnas que tengan monto se muestran :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select numerocredito as  'NumeroPrestamo' , Numerocuota as 'Numero Cuota', Fechavencimiento as 'Fecha de Vencimiento' ,
SEGUROSASISTENCIAHOSPITALARIA,SEGURODEDESGRAVAMEN,
SEGUROVOLUNTARIO,
SEGURODEGARANTIA ,
SEGURODEINCENDIO,
SEGUROFAMILIASEGURA,
SEGUROTEPROTEGEMOS,
LEGALIZACIÓNNOTARIAL,
SERVICIODETASACION,
FONDODEGARANTIAFINANCIADO ,
PRECANCELACIONOPERACIONES, 
DESFASEPLAZOPRIMERPAGO,
MIGRACIONORO ,
ASISTTECNICA ,
CARGOPTMONOCOBRADOS,
CERTIFICADODEGRAVAMEN,
GASTVISITAEINSPECCFO,
GASTOSCARTANOTARIAL,
GASTOSDEARANCELES ,
GASTOSDEPROTESTO,
GASTOSDEVIGILANCIA,
GASTOSNOTARIALES,
INTSUSPENSO ,
INTCREDITOCASTIGADOS,
LOSLAURELES,
MIGRACION,
OTROS ,
OTROSCARGOS ,
OTROSCARGOSLOSLAURELES,
OTROS36 ,
PORCOBRARREGISTRALES ,
REGINTERESNOCOBRADOS ,
VIGILANCIACULTIVOS ,
VISITASCOBRANZACLIENT ,
COMISIONES ,
CARGOSFIJOS ,
IMPUESTOALASTRANSACCIONESFINANCIERAS ,
INTERESADELANTADO ,
COMISIONFINANCIADA ,
COMISIONDIFERIDA ,
GASTOSJUDICIALES ,
INTERESREESTRUCTURA ,
SEGUROGARCUOTA ,
DESCUENTOENCOMPRADECARTERA ,
PREMIOENCOMPRADECARTERA ,
FONDODEGARANTIA ,
IMPUESTOALACIRCULACIONDECAPITALES ,
CONTRIBUCIONSIBSEGURODESGRAVAMENMICROEMPRESA ,
CONTRIBUCIONSIBSEGURODESGRAVAMENOLLADEORO ,
SEGURODECREDITO ,
INTSUSPENSOORCAII  ,
GASTOSORCA2,
PENALIDAD ,
GASTOSORCA3 ,
OTROSCARGOSORCAIV,
INTSUSPENSOORCA3 ,
INTSUSPENSOORCA4 ,
OTROSCARGOSORCA5 ,
INTSUSPENSOORCA5 ,
OTROSCARGOSORCAVI ,
INTSUSPENSOORCAVI ,
OTROSCARGOSORCAVII,
INTSUSPENSOORCAVII,
OTROSCARGOSORCAIX ,
INTSUSPENSOORCAIX ,
OTROSCARGOSORCAX ,
INTERESSUSPENSOORCAX,
OTROSCARGOSORCAXI,
INTSUSPENSOORCAXI,
OTROSCARGOSORCAXII ,
INTSUSPENSOORCAXII,
SEGDESSOLIDARIDAD ,
OTROSCARGOSORCAXIII ,
INTSUSPENSOORCAXIII ,
INTERESENSUSPENSOORCAVIII,
OTROSCARGOSORCAVIII ,
INTENSUSPENSOORCAXIV,
OTROSCARGOSORCAXIV,
OTROSCARGOSORCAXV,
INTENSUSPENSOORCAXV


 from prueba
```

Comment: hermano, aquí te dejo unos enlaces para que mejores con el SQL Server: https://www.tutorialspoint.com//ms_sql_server/index.htm - https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tutorials/ - http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver Espero te sea de utilidad, y si sientes que el idioma es una barrera, dale una patada espartana usando un traductor :D o ve por http://www.memrise.com - http://www.engvid.com - http://www.duolingo.com para aprender idiomas y le vas con todo el power 2.0! por cierto, bienvenido al sitio :D

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es averiguar que campos incluir, puedes revisar en el SQL Server la estructura de la tabla para determinar que campos son de tipo money, numeric, decimal, etc.(del tipo de dato que estén utilizando para estos montos), y luego escribir manualmente estos campos, uno a uno en la consulta:

```
select numerocredito as  'NumeroPrestamo' , Numerocuota as 'Numero Cuota', Fechavencimiento as 'Fecha de Vencimiento' ,
GASTVISITAEINSPECCFO,
GASTOSCARTANOTARIAL,
GASTOSDEARANCELES ,
GASTOSDEPROTESTO,
GASTOSDEVIGILANCIA,
GASTOSNOTARIALES
from prueba
```

También podrías obtener el listado de campos que sean del tipo que manejas para monto, mediante la metadata de la tabla, [revisa esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887370/sql-server-extract-table-meta-data-description-fields-and-their-data-types), obtener el listado de campos e incluirlos en el select de tu consulta.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es incluir en una misma consulta metadata de la tabla para que te incluya esos campos de tipo money, numeric, etc., junto con la propia data, eso no es posible.

Answer (score 0):

Yo intentaría con un sql dinamico:

```
declare @sql varchar(2000)

select @sql ='select numerocredito , Numerocuota, Fechavencimiento'
 + case when sum (GASTVISITAEINSPECCFO)>0 then ',GASTVISITAEINSPECCFO' else '' end
 + case when sum (GASTOSCARTANOTARIAL)>0 then ',GASTOSCARTANOTARIAL' else '' end
 + case when sum (GASTOSDEARANCELES)>0 then ',GASTOSDEARANCELES' else '' end
 + case when sum (GASTOSDEPROTESTO)>0 then ',GASTOSDEPROTESTO' else '' end
 + case when sum (GASTOSDEVIGILANCIA)>0 then ',GASTOSDEVIGILANCIA' else '' end
 + case when sum (GASTOSNOTARIALES)>0 then ',GASTOSNOTARIALES' else '' end
 + 'from prueba'
from prueba;

Exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Pero si hay columnas de tipo varchar, darán problema al intentar ejecutar la consulta, por el sum.

Comment: Tienes razón, pero él dice **las columnas que tengan monto se muestran**, por eso asumí que eran solo columnas de valores numéricos. Si hubieran varchar, yo cambiaria el 'SUM(CAMPO)>0' por el 'LEN(CAMPO)>0'

Comment: @reekeecast me sale un error cuando ejecuto tu query  y son como 4 que me dicen lo mismo 

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
El nombre de columna 'numerocredito' no es válido.

Comment: El nombre de las columnas los saqué del ejemplo original. Intenta hacer un `SELECT @sql` antes del EXEC para revisar que la consulta se esté armando correctamente.